# URL rewrite with pdf extension

Tags: url-rewriting

Using URL Rewrite, I would like this: www.xxx.com/view-item/abc to: www.xxx.com/item/abc.pdf. How do I use rewrite rule in .htaccess? Been looking in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t and other sites but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want the rewrite to be internal with no HTTP 301 or 302:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/view-item/(.+) /item/$1.pdf [L]
```

Mod_rewrite is a little overkill here if HTTP 301 or 302 redirects are OK. You could also use RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch ^/view-item/(.+) /item/$1.pdf
```

Comment: I am modifying a site for a friend, transferring from a web hoster to another. While trying your method, I just realized that actually the url rewrites www.xxx.com/view-item/abc to www.xxx.com/view-item.php?item=abc.pdf and the new URL is embedded with a <embed> tag. I tried various ways of your method and it seems unable to produce the correct result. I also do not understand how the variable $1.pdf is obtained, is there a possibility of $0?

Comment: I am trying to re-search more, but what is the terms or keywords i can use to know more of the symbols (.+) or ($|/), etc?

Comment: Found the answer as: RewriteRule view-item/(.+)$ view-item.php?item=$1.pdf [PT,L,QSA,B]